# What is the difference between service.Create and orgContext.AddObject?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I find that there are two ways at least to create a record in an entity like the following.

**Common Part**

```
var record = new someEntity()
{
    attribute1="test1",
    attribute2="test2" 
};

var service = new OrganizationService("CrmConnectionString");
```

**Part A**

```
service.Create(record);
```

**Part B**

```
var orgContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);
orgContext.AddObject(record);
orgContext.SaveChanges();
```

What is the difference?And which is better?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Part A uses the raw create method of the organization service proxy. This operation directly creates the record.

Part B makes use of the OrganizationServiceContext, which implements the [Unit of Work pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). Your operations are not transmitted to the server until you call `SaveChanges()`

Which is better? It depends on your requirements. If you only want to create a record on the go -> use the service. If you do multiple things which form a logical unit take version B.